# how to enable font-family tool in WYSIWYG editor in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, sql

[image]

i want display fontfamily in the wysiwyg editor in magento2

Answer (score 0):

This below might help with your question. Beside, you can also take help from this guide as well: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/cms/editor.html

[image]